# jquery.cookie.js hiding always

Tags: jquery, cookies, hide, page-refresh

I'm trying to hide a div when page is refreshed for 1 day after first visit to site. I'm using [jquery.cookie.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

I'm missing something obvious but this being my first cookie I don't know what it is.

```
$.cookie('cookie', 'oreo', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!$.cookie("cookie"))
    {
        $.cookie("cookie", "oreo");
        $("#cooked").show();
    }else{
        $("#cooked").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kept looking for answer and found it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if( $.cookie('showOnlyOne') ){
    $('#cooked').hide();
    $('#swipe-scroll').hide();
} else {
    $.cookie('showOnlyOne', 'showOnlyOne', { expires: 1,  path: '/'  });
    $('#cooked').show();
    $('#swipe-scroll').show();
}
```

});

I'm guessing it's because I defined the cookie before the function. That said, it works great now.